# How to fix build android by cordova?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, npm

I have error, on project ionic like this:

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2.

I've equated the version of all like node js, cordova, npm, according to the requirement. Please help me

Full picture:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f8ri.png

Comment: Please post all the components version installed and also the 'full picture' for others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to update android SDK and choose support from extra menu in android manager

Comment: I have updated sdk manager use android studio, like this url https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html, but still not working.

Comment: the requirement is
$ node -v    # v6.10.3
$ npm -v     # 3.10.10
$ cordova -v # 7.0.1
$ ionic -v   # 3.1.2

Comment: Did you install support dependency from extra menu in sdk manager